# session works on localhost but sometimes not working on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is a controller where i'm creating a session :

```
public function login(){
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $res = $this->register_model->loginUser();
        if($res['result'] === true){
            // declare session variables
            $user = $res['info']; // array containing user information
            // set session variables
            $_SESSION['storeId'] = $user->str_id;
            $_SESSION['sName'] = $user->str_nme;
            $_SESSION['sId'] = $user->str_identifier;
            $_SESSION['hash'] = $user->hash;
            $res['info'] = null;
        }
    } else {
        $res = array('result'=>false,'msg'=>'Login failed. Please try again');
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

and this is a controller where i retrieve a session

Comment: what is the error you got??

Comment: Why you mixing php session code with you CI session??

Comment: Please, provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/session-handling-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function login(){
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $res = $this->register_model->loginUser();
        if($res['result'] === true){
            // declare session variables
            $user = $res['info']; // array containing user information
            // set session variables

            $this->load->library('session');
            $newdata = array(
                'storeId'  => $user->str_id,
                'sName'     => $user->str_nme,
                'sId' => $user->str_identifier,
                'hash' => $user->hash,
                'info' => null,
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

        }
    } else {
        $res = array('result'=>false,'msg'=>'Login failed. Please try again');
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```